# Is there a repository of r-exams questions other than the one included in the official package?

Tags: r-markdown, r-exams

There are more than 30 questions in the official `r-exams` package http://www.r-exams.org/templates/, in addition to other important contributions http://www.r-exams.org/general/distancelearning/. I am not suggesting that they are insufficient. I just want to have more references to design my own questions, although I have advanced a lot, considering that I am not a programmer or a developer. I don't know if there are more repositories. In case the answer to this question is negative, I suggest creating more repositories, in which questions / exercises are shared, preferably with many commented lines of code, thinking of those newbies, like me. I have some questions / exercises -not many- to share with those who, eventually, find them some pedagogical value.

Note: Could commented lines of code be added to exercises in the `r-exams` repository?

Thank you.

Comment: (1) I don't think this question fits StackOverflow very well. It is not a programming question in the narrow sense and will likely lead to opinion based answers and recommendations. (2) If you want to discuss questions like this, the forum on R-Forge is the more suitable venue for it (https://R-Forge.F-project.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=4377). There have been related discussions in the past already.  (3) A few R/exams users have posted links from the forum to their repositories which may or may not contain types of exercises you find useful.

Comment: (4) This is an open-source world! A vague suggestion like _"creating more repositories"_ is not likely to generate immediate responses - and even if, it is not so clear whether these would contain the kind of guidance you are looking for. I recommend that you engage with colleagues locally and try to work on developing content together. Or try to find like-minded users online (e.g., in our forum or on Twitter etc.). In case of concrete problems, you are very welcome to ask questions here or on Twitter. Good luck!